# simple ProxyRequire is not working?

Tags: node.js, sinon

i have been stuck with making Proxy-require work, below is my code and test file. I am trying to stub a function inside the code file using proxyRequire

```
   //createSignature.js
    'use strict';
    var keys = require('../../../../utils/keys');

    module.exports = function createSignature(transaction) {
      try {
        let prvkeyDecoded = keys.bs58_encode('test');
        return true
      } catch (err) {
      }
    };
```

here is the test file

```
//createSignature_unit.js
'use strict';    
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
const chai = require('chai');
chai.use(sinonChai);
const sinon = require('sinon');
const createSignature = require('./createSignature');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noPreserveCache().noCallThru();

const keysMock =
  {
    bs58_encode: sinon.stub()
  };
 const test = 
   proxyquire('./createSignature', {
     '../../../../utils/keys': keysMock
  })

describe('test backend', () => {
  it("Create Signature with stubs", function() {
    test('test')
    expect(keysMock.bs58_encode).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });
});
```

my `test` function is not called, and `keysMock.bs58_encode`also is not been called even once. Am i missing something?

```
//output window 
 1) Create Signature with stubs


  0 passing (9ms)
  1 failing

  1) test backend
       Create Signature with stubs:
     AssertionError: expected stub to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
      at Context.<anonymous> (createSignature_unit.js:37:46)
```

In addition to this if i just call

```
it("Create Signature with stubs", function() {
    expect(test('fg')).to.be.true
    //expect(keysMock.bs58_encode).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });
```

i get output as `AssertionError: expected undefined to be true`

Comment: I saw you file name as `createSignature:js` with semicolon, is that right?

Comment: Looks like `test('fg')` is either never got called or it went into `catch` statement. Perhaps you can try to add some `console.log` statement in the function or set breakpoints to see how the code flows.

Answer (score 2):

Your stub wrong function as mock. In test, you stub `bs58_encode` but in the source file, you use `bs58_decode`. Change it into `bs58_decode` should fix it.

```
const keysMock = {
  bs58_decode: sinon.stub() // change to decode
};
const test =
  proxyquire('./createSignature', {
    '../../../../utils/keys': keysMock
  })

describe('test backend', () => {
  it("Create Signature with stubs", function () {
    test('test')
    expect(keysMock.bs58_decode).to.have.been.calledOnce; // change to decode
  });
});
```